# JPA 2.0: How to avoid full class name in `SELECT NEW full.class.Name`?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constructor, jpa-2.0

How can I avoid putting FQCN into `SELECT NEW ...`?

Packages are often changed during refactoring, and that may cause troubles.

Not sure if I can do something for that in JPA;  I am also happy with Hibernate 3.6 solution (`Ejb3Configuration`).

Note that class used in `SELECT NEW` is not an entity, so standard trick with `<class>` in `persistence.xml` doesn't work (YMMV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the spec, the constructor name has to be fully qualified, JPA spec 4.8.2. So no, you can't avoid it. And why can't you just use MyClass.class.getName() and hence cope with refactorings?

Comment: I had named queries and didn't realize that I can use static calls in there too.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://vladmihalcea.com/dto-projection-jpa-query/.

Here you find a solution based on `ClassImportIntegrator` from https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but a true refactoring will change the package in the query, too. You might consider choosing a better tool for your refactorings if that's what's holding you back.